# Deploying Web Apps as war Files

Tags: java, deployment, tomcat, web-applications

I'm having some trouble uploading and getting my web app on the net with my chosen host.  I built a war file in Net Beans and asked my host to deploy it for me.  This worked fine but to access it I had to point my browser to:

```
www.myDomain.co.uk/explodedWar
```

What of course I wanted was to be able to access it just by pointing my browser at:

```
www.myDomain.co.uk
```

The war file contains the whole app, index.html, images, classes etc.

Is this possible or am I missing something ? ?

Answer (score 4):

You can call the war ROOT.war but the best way is to change the context path in the servlet container. To do this in Tomcat you would add the following to your server.xml:

```
<context path="" docBase="explodedWar" debug="0"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you name your war ROOT.war (in Tomcat) it should do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

This is a question you need to ask your host about since they are deploying it for you.